# Sinks and Sources

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a differential equation $x'=f(x)$ that has three equilibrium points that are

1. all sinks;
2. all sources.

So two differential equations total. Help!

Comment: Can you add a little detail yo tour question? Do you just need any solution?

Comment: I need an example equation that has three equilibrium points, all of which are sinks, and also an example equation having three equilibrium points, all of which are sources.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a function, $f$, that has three zeros, and to ensure these zeros are all sinks of the differential equation, make sure that $\frac{df}{dx} < 0$ at each zero. Note this requires that $f$ is a discontinuous function. As a specific example, with zeros at $-1$, $0$ and $1$,
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
-x-1 \;, & x \le -\frac{1}{2} \\
-x \;, & -\frac{1}{2} < x \le \frac{1}{2} \\
-x+1 \;, & x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right. \;.
$$
With instead $-f(x)$, the zeros are sources.

Answer (score 0):

hint: pay attention root of this equation x'=f(x) is  equilibrium points let $f(x_0)=0$ therefore$$if\quad  f'(x_0)\lt0 \quad then\quad x_0 \quad is\quad sink $$ and $$if\quad  f'(x_0)\gt0 \quad then\quad x_0 \quad is\quad source $$  now you can find   $f(x)$ for "1"  let $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x)$ s.t $f'(x)=3x^2-2(a+b)+ab\lt0$ then calculate lower bound and upper bound for a,b also  do it for second part   $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x)$ then find a,b such that $f'(x)=3x^2-2(a+b)+ab\gt0$